# Eliminar un registro de la BD con un botón

Tags: php, html, css, phpmyadmin

Hago me pregunta aquí ya que necesito de la ayuda del que sea que pueda solucionar mi problema.
Estoy trabajando en una página web como proyecto para una materia de mi universidad, ahora mismo estoy metido en un problema el cual es que no puedo eliminar el registro que se tiene.
Quiero resaltar que no se nada de HTML, CSS Y/O PHP, por lo que puede que mi código no sea el mejor de todos (código resultado de distintas búsquedas en internet y el copiado de códigos terceros).

El caso es que quiero poder borrar el registro del usuario y así eliminarlo de la BD llevándolo automáticamente a la página del login. A continuación muestra el HTML completo y el PHP

El código donde envió el id está en la parte comentada como

```
HTML:

<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['correo'])){

} else {
header("Location: index.php");
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Cuenta</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/paginas.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
  <div class = "logoheader">
    <img src="../IMG/IconoBlanco.png" class="avatar" alt="Avatar Image">
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li center> <a href="taxis.php">Taxis</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="choferes.php">Choferes</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="rutas.php">Rutas</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="cuenta.php">Cuenta</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  
  
  <div class="Cajabts">
  <form method = "POST" action="../PHP/subirfoto.php">
  Nombres: <br> 
  Apellidos: <br>
  Sexo: <br>
  <div class="boton">
    <input type="submit" name = "cambiar-foto" value="Agregar o modificar foto.">
    <input type="button" name="modificarcuenta" value = "Modificar cuenta">
    <a href = "../PHP/logout.php"><input type="button" name="cerrarsesion" value = "Cerrar 
 sesion"></a>
    </div>
    </form>

    <!--BORRADO DE REGISTROS-->
   
    <a href = "../PHP/borrado.php?id=<?php$row["id"];?>">
    <input type="button" value="Eliminar cuenta"></a>

    </div>    
    </main>

    <footer>
        <p>Moving</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:
<?php
session_start();

```
include("db.php");

$id = $_GET["id"];
$eliminado = "DELETE FROM usuarios2 WHERE ID = '$id'";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $eliminado);



if($resultado){

session_destroy();
header("Location: ../PAGINAS/index.php");

}else{
echo "error";
}

?>
```

Comment: Dale un espacio de separación y ponle un **echo** a esto: `<?php$row["id"];?>`.  Es decir, que quede así: `<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>`, para que puedas poner correctamente el id en el formulario para después ejecutar el botón.

Comment: y que error te sale, ya lo solucionaste?

Comment: @masterguru no me funciona con tu forma amigo

Comment: @DerekRiosRamirez Ya veo. Es porque el $row no está definido en ninguna parte, no me miré bien todo tu código.  Supongo que ese php lo abres de alguna forma usando el id del usuario en la url, por lo tanto lo debes recuperar de alli mejor.